# Using JSON vs XML for transporting Data to server side (J2EE)

Tags: servlets

the below line is taken from a website

```
**JSON Objects are serializable and where as XML is not .**
```

Assume that i am passing a JSON Object from UI to the server (J2EE Language)\
Could you please tell me in what way will it effect if i use XML or JSON for transporting the data from a HTML/JSP to the server ??

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transportation of `JSON` over network between client and server is more lean and lightweight.

For example, to transport a simple Animal object over the network in XML may look something like this:

```
<Animal>
<Name>Lion</Name>
<Sex>Male</Sex>
</Animal>
```

In `JSON`, it would look something like this:

```
{Animal: {Name: "Lion", Sex: "Male"}}
```

Due to the data structure of JSON, interpreters parse `JSON` string faster than `XML` string.

Comment: I agree , thank you very much , where is  serialization concep in this data formats

Comment: I have not come across that XML is not Serializable, perhaps if you share your website link so we may have a look together.

Comment: Hi , thank you very much for the reply , but i was asking how serialization playing role during transfer of data .

Comment: XML and JSON are data transport objects you pass from your server to client, vice versa, and therefore they are flattened (serialized), they will not be serialized further, there isn't going to be XML -> Serialized XML, the XML itself is "flattened", therefore, going by XML vs JSON, you may find it advantageous in your situation to consider JSON vs XML.

Comment: thank you very much as u asked to share the site taht XML is not serializable  "http://ajaxian.com/archives/json-vs-xml-the-debate"  search for this that it is essentially serialized Javascript objects which makes it fit better client side scripting